# Swagger codegen generated client access control issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, cors, swagger, codegen

I have generated a client side app with swagger codegen for a specific API, the [javascript](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/tree/master/samples/client/petstore/javascript) version. Initialized it with npm etc. etc. everything claps.

However when i try to send a get request with the generated api from my localhost to http://81.2.241.234:8080/species i get the following error:

> Error: Request has been terminated
>   Possible causes: the network is offline, Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin, the page is being unloaded, etc.
>       at Request.crossDomainError (bundle.js:2967)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (bundle.js:3049)

The mentioned headers are present on the servers response if i call the url from chrome.

Some code for easier understanding:

```
var speciesApiInstance = new index.SpeciesServiceApi();

var opts = {
'start': 0, // Number | start position
'count': 10, // Number | count
'orderfield': "name", // String | order by
'orderdirection': "ASC" // String | order direction
};

var callback = function(error, data, response) {
if (error) {
    console.error(error);
} else {
    console.log('API called successfully. Returned data: ' + data);
}
 };
speciesApiInstance.getSpecies(opts, callback);
```

What am I doing wrong? Couldn't find an answer in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:** I was using HTTPS connection, the mentioned IP connects with http only, thus the preflight request failed. Modified the connection url to call the API with http and it works properly.